# Androidx Naviagtion - Pass custom object to destination fragment

Tags: android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-deep-link

I need to pass a custom object from one fragment to another fragment. I use androidx navigation for navigation between fragments. I had to use `deepLink` for navigation for my use case.

The navigation graph with the destination fragment has,

```
    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/ListFragment"
       android:name="com.joseph.learning.ListFragment"
       android:label="ListFragment">
    
       <argument android:name="todoItem"
        app:argType="com.joseph.learning.models.todoItem" />

      <deepLink app:uri="android-app://androidx.navigation/todoList/{todoItem}" />
  </fragment>
```

And from the source fragment, the navigation is initiated like

```
findNavController().navigate(
  Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/todoList/$item"),
  NavOptions.Builder()
      .setEnterAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_in_right)
      .setExitAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_out_left)
      .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_out_right)
      .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_in_left)
      .build()
 )
```

But this fails as soon as it executes with below error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parcelables don't support default values.
        at androidx.navigation.NavType$ParcelableType.parseValue(NavType.java:679)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType.parseAndPut(NavType.java:96)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDeepLink.parseArgument(NavDeepLink.java:306)
        ...
```

If incase, the custom object as argument is replaced with string or integer, then the navigation works without any issues. Also the passed data can be extracted in the destination fragment using `navArgs()`

What should be done to pass custom object across fragments ?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Pretty disappointed to see no answers posted yet. Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: @PurushPawar You need to implement Parcelable in the data class which you want to pass across. In that way, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work and crashes with the same exception. There's actually an issue filed for this in google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148523779. I'm surprised how it's working at your end.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types)

> Routes, deep links, and URIs with their arguments can be parsed from strings. This is not possible using custom data types such as Parcelables and Serializables as seen in the above table.

> **Solution**: To pass around custom complex data, store the data elsewhere such as a ViewModel or database and only pass an identifier while navigating; then retrieve the data in the new location after navigation has concluded.